# Legend not visible in matplotlib, instead a small square box appears in the specified location

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I am trying to make one legend for all subplots in matplotlib. However, the legend does not appear at all, instead I can see a small gray lined square in the specified location. The following figure explains it better (the upper right corner of the figure): [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGxQt.png)

Code snippet:

```
sns.set(context='notebook')

fig,axs = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(7,4))
date_form = DateFormatter("%m-%d")


axs[0,0].plot(time,diag[:,0],color='r')
axs[0,0].plot(time,diag_ctrl[:,0],color='k')
#axs[0,0].set_title('Net heat flux')

axs[0,1].plot(time,diag[:,1],color='r')
axs[0,1].plot(time,diag_ctrl[:,1],color='k')
#axs[0,1].set_title('Sensible heat flux')

axs[1,0].plot(time,diag[:,2],color='r')
axs[1,0].plot(time,diag_ctrl[:,2],color='k')
#axs[1,0].set_title('Latent heat flux')
               
axs[1,1].plot(time,diag[:,3],color='r')
axs[1,1].plot(time,diag_ctrl[:,3],color='k')
#axs[1,1].set_title('LWR')

for ax in axs.flat:
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_form)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.AutoLocator())

lines, labels = fig.axes[-1].get_legend_handles_labels()
fig.legend(lines, ('sensitivity','control'), loc = 'upper right')
plt.show()
```

Comment: You may try to do:
leg = fig.legend(lines, ('sensitivity','control'), loc = 'upper right')
leg.set_zorder(10)

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the label for each plot directly while using `plot` method.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

n = 100
time = np.arange(n)

sns.set(context='notebook')

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(time,np.random.randn(n),label='sensitivity')
ax.plot(time,np.random.randn(n),label='control')

fig.legend(loc = 'upper right')
plt.show()
```

Returns

[image]

You may only need to do it for your last plot.
Your code can be something like:

```
sns.set(context='notebook')

fig,axs = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(7,4))
date_form = DateFormatter("%m-%d")


axs[0,0].plot(time,diag[:,0],color='r')
axs[0,0].plot(time,diag_ctrl[:,0],color='k')
#axs[0,0].set_title('Net heat flux')

axs[0,1].plot(time,diag[:,1],color='r')
axs[0,1].plot(time,diag_ctrl[:,1],color='k')
#axs[0,1].set_title('Sensible heat flux')

axs[1,0].plot(time,diag[:,2],color='r')
axs[1,0].plot(time,diag_ctrl[:,2],color='k')
#axs[1,0].set_title('Latent heat flux')
               
axs[1,1].plot(time,diag[:,3],color='r',label='sensitivity')
axs[1,1].plot(time,diag_ctrl[:,3],color='k',label='control')
#axs[1,1].set_title('LWR')

for ax in axs.flat:
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_form)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.AutoLocator())

axs[1,1].legend(loc = 'upper right')
plt.show()
```